# Regex to match all parameters in an URL

Tags: regex

I have a list of URLs with parameters in them and I need to strip them of all the parameters.

Sample data:

```
https://www.example.com/highlights/on-sale-01304&sa=U&ei=2ca1VJXQOYHnsASG3YGYCg&ved=0CBMQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNHucW7fFrA35qeeJbUlAbsPFQNxLg
https://www.example.com/collections/view-all-01240&sa=U&ei=2ca1VJXQOYHnsASG3YGYCg&ved=0CBgQFjAB&usg=AFQjCNGhZzf7rsslCqgHSngyFAbw_nQmvQ
https://www.example.com/highlights/overstock-and-clearance-01217&sa=U&ei=2ca1VJXQOYHnsASG3YGYCg&ved=0CB0QFjAC&usg=AFQjCNHMfQBA4AP51_ikOGyoGEx-aB0-wQ
```

I have tried this `(\?|\&)([^=]+)\=([^&]+)`but it matches only a single parameter at a time and basically need to match everything after the `?` sign.

Comment: what would the desired output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a `\n` character in all the character classes. Because `[^=]+` matches also a newline character.

```
([?&])([^=\n]+)\=([^&\n]+)
```

Then replace the matched characters with an empty string.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zC4hA5/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to strip EVERYTHING after the '?', then use something like `/?.+/g`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:\?|\&)(?:[^=]+)\=(?:[^&\s]+)
```

Try this.See demo.Replace by `empty string`.

https://regex101.com/r/fA6wE2/9